# "always have been" vs "be always"

Tags: present-perfect

In the movie Dead Silence, a man says to a woman:

> Yeah, but then you always have been a little feisty, my girl.

In this case, why does he use "always have been" rather than "be always":

> Yeah, but then you are always a little feisty, my girl.

Comment: From the present perfect we understand that the speaker has known the woman for quite a long time.  Their relationship is not a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, nobody gave you an answer so I will do it.

> It is the *present perfect* that indicates that the above started in
>   the past and is still true.

She was a little feisty girl and she still is a little feisty girl.

**"always"** is an *'adverbs of frequency'* which tells us that the statement was true for all that time from the past until now.

Usually though *'adverbs of frequency'* go after the first verb of a multiple verb sequence. So it should have been:

- Yeah, but then you have always been a little feisty, my girl.

But here the speaker decided to emphasize the word "always" and make the sentence more idiomatic.